# How to publish An Azure function that connects to a storage account

Tags: azure

Just wondering what the best practice when it comes to deploying / publishing an azure function... that needs to connect to a database / storage account. I'm new to .net and new to azure ... so i apologize in advance for any noob question.

We have the following logic in a powershell deploy script for our azure function (HTTP Triggered):

```
#login with service principal
az login --service-principal --username $UID --password $PASSWD --tenant $TENANT --allow-no-subscriptions

#set the subscription we want to use
az account set --subscription $SUBSCRIPTION_ID


#create resource group
az group create -n $GRP_NAME -l $LOCATION

#create resources defined in JSON
az deployment group create --resource-group $GRP_NAME --template-file "./resources/azfnResources.json"

func azure functionapp publish $FN_APP_NAME --publish-local-settings -i --overwrite-settings -y
```

This is what our local.settings.json file looks like:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values":{
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
        "WidgetStorageQueue":"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=asdfasdf;AccountKey=<key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
    }
}
```

**Problem**

This type of an approach requires manual intervention.  We can just let this script run because... we have to update the connection string AFTER the resources in the azfnResources.json file have been created ... and BEFORE the functionapp publish command is triggered.

**Question**

Based on the documentation, it seems that the local.settings.json file needed when I want to debug / run my code locally ... and be able to connect to the backend storage. (which lives upstream).  Makes sense.

What is the best way to automate this script such that no manual work is needed to update the connection string after the storage account is generated from scratch?

Maybe we shouldn't use the local.settings.json file to publish?  Is Maybe we should just make that something the developer has to manually update on his / her own.

Answer (score 0):

When publishing, your Azure Function should read settings from Azure Functions App Settings using environment variables.

You can find more information in the following links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#settings

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#environment-variables